# Method 'get_IsBindingRedirectSupported' does not have an implementation

Tags: asp.net-webpages

So I'm trying to create a ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2) website in Visual Studio 2012 but when running the site I get this error.

```
Method 'get_IsBindingRedirectSupported' in type 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PackageManager.WebProjectSystem' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
```

After trying to find anything useful with my dear friend Google I'm at a loss.

Does anyone know the reason for this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: No, but +1 and a favorite on this; nearly every time I start a Razor v2 website, a new plethora of seemingly random errors bubble up, this one being the most recent. I've been removing (*via NuGet*) many of the unnecessary packages (*OpenID, etc.; damn near everything really*) and nearly every time I get problems, and nearly every time the problems aren't the same, and nearly every time I ask myself, "*Why am I still using this?*"

Answer (score 1):

I started to get this error after I updated NuGet.Core.dll from version 1.6.30117.9648 to version 2.11.1.812

The remedy (as advised by [Kirschstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15691/kirschstein)) was to delete the System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll file from my bin directory

Comment: Weird, you think there would be more to it!

Answer (score 0):

When running into the problem, these are the steps I took to fix them.

1. Remove the System.Web.WebPages.Administration reference from your projects.
2. Navigate to this folder in your project: YourProject/YourProject and find the xml config file Packages.
3. Open that file and remove the line containing the System.Web.WebPages.Administration.
4. Navigate to the Packages folder in your solution and find the folder named 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration*'/lib/net40.
5. Delete the System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll

Comment: In my case I use the System.Web.WebPAges.Administration.dll in my proyect, so removing it is not an option.